# Update Asp.Net Claims via SQL statement?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to add a claim to an existing User, but the query I wrote (and am running in SSQL Management Studio) below doesn't work. Is the query wrong, or is this just not possible?

```
update [test_MIM].[dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] 
set ClaimType = 'EmployeeNumber',
ClaimValue = '1',
--Id = f.Id,
UserId = f.UserName
from (select Id,UserName FROM [test_MIM].[dbo].[AspNetUsers] where UserName='abc@gmail.com') as f
```

I commented out the Id column because when I included it the query failed (possibly because Id was auto-generated)

Comment: Why does the 3rd column look like `--Id` ?

Comment: is this stored procedure ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I updated my post to include an answer to that at the bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead use a `update-join` construct like

```
update a 
set ClaimType = 'EmployeeNumber',
ClaimValue = '1',
UserId = f.UserName
from [test_MIM].[dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] a
join [test_MIM].[dbo].[AspNetUsers] f 
on a.id = f.id
where f.UserName = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

Comment: When I tried that I got: `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'd2bba743-34f9-4644-a4fa-cde7536cec51' to data type int.`

Comment: @Rilcon42 that's cause of condition `on a.id = f.id`. is there a matching column between the tables? you can join on them then

Comment: no, there is no matching column, I am simply trying to add a new row with the data to the AspNetClaims table

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use `join` in your update statement,what `join` does is it joins two or multiple tables together in one statement :

```
UPDATE NameHere SET ClaimType = 'EmployeeNumber',ClaimValue = '1', UserId f.UserName FROM [test_MIM].[dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] NameHere JOIN [test_MIM].[dbo].[AspNetUsers] f  on NameHere.id = f.id where f.UserName = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

But it is not ideal,rather pass parameters for each column , then not only that you can save your app from SQL-Injection but also will be able to set column's data-type which might get rid of other problems. A sample :

```
  UPDATE NameHere SET ClaimType = @ClaimType,ClaimValue = @claimValue, UserId = @Uname FROM [test_MIM].[dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] NameHere JOIN [test_MIM].[dbo].[AspNetUsers] f  on NameHere.id = @NewID where f.UserName = @NewUserName
```

If you are using `SqlCommand`,then you can use the parameters as follows :

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClaimType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "claimingTyoeString" ////Assuming 'cmd' is the SqlCommand

 .......

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```