# Update asp.net claims when not logged in as the user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims-based-identity

I am trying to have users create an account on my site, then have someone on my team add the appropriate claims for that user after they have created an account. How can I do this? I tried doing it via an SQL command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564340/update-asp-net-claims-via-sql-statement/49564621#49564621), but never got it working. Is there a built in way to add a claim to another user account?

Comment: ow, you are using my answer ?? So, u mean, u want to update data of the table,right ?

Comment: just include the table name and field names,i'll post an answer :)

Comment: You are looking for [UserManager.AddClaimAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151621(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager%602.AddClaimAsync(%601,System.Security.Claims.Claim))

Comment: Thanks trailmax that was what I was looking for